# Customizing annotation with Seaborn's FacetGrid

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to customize some figures with the Seaborn module in Python, but I haven't had luck creating custom labels or annotations. I've got some code that generates the following figure:

```
plot = sns.FacetGrid(data = data, col = 'bot', margin_titles = True).set_titles('Human', 'Bot')
bins = np.linspace(0, 2000, 15)
plot = plot.map(plt.hist, 'friends_count', color = 'black', lw = 0, bins = bins)
plot.set_axis_labels('Number Following', 'Count')
sns.despine(left = True, bottom = True)
```

[image]

I'd like to do two things: 1. replace the default factor labels, e.g. 'bot = 0.0', with meaningful text, and 2. draw vertical lines at the mean number following for each category.

Here's a self-contained example:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fake = pd.DataFrame({'val': [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3], 'group': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]})
plot = sns.FacetGrid(data = fake, col = 'group', margin_titles = True).set_titles('zero', 'one')
plot = plot.map(plt.hist, 'val', color = 'black', lw = 0)
sns.despine(left = True, bottom = True)
```

Anyone know how to customize FacetGrids?

Comment: check out the `FacetGrid.set_titles` method.

Comment: Yeah, tried that but nothing renders. Any thoughts on making vertical lines at different points on each?

Comment: Not sure what "nothing renders" means. If you tried things and didn't work, you should add that too the question. Also it is much easier to help when your question has a self-contained example that someone can copy and paste to build on. Perhaps you could use one of the example seaborn datasets that are used in the tutorial.

Comment: I used `set_titles` in the question, but my titles don't render. I just included a self-contained example of identical behavior.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

A few things about `set_titles`.

First, the default titles are drawn in the `FacetGrid.map` method, so if you want to change the titles, you have to call `set_titles` *after* plotting, or else they will be overwritten.

Second, if you look at the docstring for the method, it doesn't just take an arbitrary list of titles. It provides a way to change how the title is rendered using the column variable name and value:

```
template : string
    Template for all titles with the formatting keys {col_var} and
    {col_name} (if using a `col` faceting variable) and/or {row_var}
    and {row_name} (if using a `row` faceting variable).
```

So the easiest way to have "meaningful text" is to use meaningful data in your dataframe. Take this example with random data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'val': np.random.randn(100),
                   'group': np.repeat([0, 1], 50)})
```

If you want "group" to be `zero` and `one`, you should just change that column, or make a new one:

```
df["group"] = df["group"].map({0: "zero", 1; "one"})
```

Then say you don't want to have the variable name in the title, the proper way to use `FacetGrid.set_titles` would be

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(data=df, col='group')
g.map(plt.hist, 'val', color='black', lw=0)
g.set_titles('{col_name}')
```

[image: some bar graphs]

If you don't want to change the data you're plotting, then you'll have to set the attributes on the matplotlib axes directly, something like:

```
for ax, title in zip(g.axes.flat, ['zero', 'one']):
    ax.set_title(title)
```

Note that this is less preferable to the above method because you have to be very careful about making sure the order of your list is correct and that it isn't going to change, whereas getting the information from the dataframe itself will be much more robust.

To plot the mean, you'll need to create a small function that can be passed to `FacetGrid.map`. There are [multiple examples](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/axis_grids.html#mapping-custom-functions-onto-the-grid) of how to do this in the tutorial. In this case, it's quite easy:

```
def vertical_mean_line(x, **kwargs):
    plt.axvline(x.mean(), **kwargs)
```

Then all you need is to re-plot:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(data=df, col='group')
g.map(plt.hist, 'val', color='black', lw=0)
g.map(vertical_mean_line, 'val')
g.set_titles('{col_name}')
```

[image: some more bar graphs]

Comment: Great answer. IMO the trouble with encoding data with the labels you'd use for visualization is that it precludes applying transformations on the data later (without repeatedly re-encoding). For example, if I wanted to center and scale I'd have to convert those labels back into [0, 1]. Hoping to see better support for figure labeling and annotation in the future. Would be great to have something elegant and powerful like ggplot2 for Python.

Comment: @erinshellman have you seen yhat's ggplot library? http://ggplot.yhathq.com/docs/facet_grid.html