# Is there a way to specify subplots titles in FacetGrid seaborn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I could not find a way to specify titles for subplots in FacetGrid in seaborn. Currently title is forced-set to be "grp="

```
master_df = pd.concat([source_school_small_uniform.assign(grp="taxi"),
                       source_school_large_uniform.assign(grp="bus")])

g = sns.FacetGrid(master_df, col="grp", hue="method", col_wrap=2, ...)
```

For the very least -- is there a way to remove "grp=" from the title?

[image]

Comment: This question has been asked and answered before already. Did you delete it?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest It wasn't answered correctly and I rephrased the question altogether. The question is how to assign different names to subplots, removing "grp=" is sort of helping to overcome this issue, partially, but it is really not the point of a question. I wonder how to set a title to a plot, not how to rename groups in Pandas and then force matplotlib ignore grps while displaying names of groups it pulls from DataFrame. What I really need is to specify titles for each subplot in seaborn. I could not find it in seaborn docs, maybe there is a way to do it through matplotlib api..

Comment: But if I remember correctly, the answer to that question did show how to do it. Namely loop over the axes and set the respective title via `g.axes[i,j].set_title(my_title)`.

Comment: It did not seem correct since I tried it and it did not work, and someone else was downvoting that person (not me), so I felt bad for possibly confusing people and tried rephrasing the question and goal. If it was correct and person wasn't downvoted (for possibly my bad phrasing of the goal) I would not redo it. But yeah .I just found that g = (g.map(sns.scatterplot).set_titles(<my_title>)) does the job. I think it is in a nutshell what you just said

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just had the same question and found this to work well: `g.set_titles('{col_name}')`. If you are dealing with a row x col plot, then you could use something along the lines of `g.set_titles('{row_name}' ' | ' '{col_name}')`. In addition, this post can be useful too [Customizing annotation with Seaborn's FacetGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31632372/customizing-annotation-with-seaborns-facetgrid).

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but perhaps this is still useful. Here's how I recently did this and it works well.

```
    import numpy as np
    import seaborn as sns
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    ordered_titlelist = ["Title 1","Title 2", ...,"Title N"]
    for idx,ax in enumerate(g.axes.flat):
        ax.set_title(ordered_titlelist[idx])
```

"flat" is an attribute of the numpy ndarrays and allows you to iterate through n x m axes. This is useful for iterating through FacetGrids and axes objects made through the `plt.subplots()` function as well.